# How to align two uibuttons in storyboard

Tags: swift, button, uibutton, swift2

how do i make two button "Like" and "Comment" with equal space on the left of "Like", equal space in the middle of "Like" and "Comment", and equal space on the right of "Comment" depending on the phone size

here is an image example:

[image]

Comment: Is your storyboard is with size class or auto resize?

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala yes

Comment: Means with size class?

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala yes you are correct

Comment: Tell us what you already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it works for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code it is a bit different approach but hope it will work for you. It is better to set these constraints directly in Storyboard.

```
let deviceWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
let buttonWidth = 75
let equalPadding = (deviceWidth - (2 * buttonWidth))/3
let centerXOfLikeButton = -(buttonWidth/2 + equalPadding/2)
let centerXOfCommentButton = (buttonWidth/2 + equalPadding/2)

// Like button constraints
let likeBtnTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)    
let likeBtnWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem:  nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: buttonWidth)    
let likeBtnHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem:  nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40)    
let likeBtnXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute:  .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: centerXOfLikeButton)

self.view.addConstraint(likeBtnTopConstraint)
self.view.addConstraint(likeBtnWidthConstraint)
self.view.addConstraint(likeBtnHeightConstraint)
self.view.addConstraint(likeBtnXConstraint)

// Comment button constraints
let commentBtnTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)    
let commentBtnWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem:  nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: buttonWidth)    
let commentBtnHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: .Equal,  toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40)    
let commentBtnXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view,  attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: centerXOfCommentButton)

self.view.addConstraint(commentBtnTopConstraint)
self.view.addConstraint(commentBtnWidthConstraint)
self.view.addConstraint(commentBtnHeightConstraint)
self.view.addConstraint(commentBtnXConstraint)
```

Using storyboard, please refer screenshots provided below
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: how can i do it in storyboard and not programmatically?

Comment: Set Both button's Top constraint, Width constraint(Both button's width should be same), Height constraint and horizontal centers in container(Align X). Now, create an outlet of Align X constraint for both the buttons. And set the following value to those constraints:
let centerXOfLikeButton = -(buttonWidth/2 + equalPadding/2)
let centerXOfCommentButton = (buttonWidth/2 + equalPadding/2)

Comment: @johnjay22113 Check my updated answer using storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Crate Two button with equal width and equal height and give "titleEdgeInsets" on each button as bellow,

```
let insert = likeButton.frame.width / 4
    commentButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: insert)
    likeButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: insert, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```